# best manner to learn how to make a program that can handle animation

Tags: c#, python, c++, user-interface

this is my first question on this website, I only have experience looking for questions other people made. I am very interested in machine learning and there is a youtube channel that hosts videos like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOFws_hhZs8&t=27s

My goal is not only to replicate the internal mathematical process of the program, wich I am confident I know how to do, but creating a program that can have the graphics handling that the one of the video has. As a physicist, my programs, from the computer science point of view, are extremely basic:They pick a text file, do some calculations, and write/plot data results. I already know python, fortran (useless for this task) and a little bit of C. So, finally my question:

What programming language and IDE would you recommend me to learn?

Thank you so much

Comment: You should have had a look at the help center for how to ask and what to as here. This is off-topic on stackoverflow, but there are other sites on this network where this kind of question is on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this website 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

It's a very useful knowledge base with courses/tutorials for machine learning in Python

I just use Sublime Text as an editor for Python.

I'm not sure about the animation though, I have never animated anything myself in Python, but the Canvas class might be of help  here

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_canvas.htm

Comment: By the way, as @SirRufo said, be sure to check out all the cool sites stackexchange has!